# Does a server have anything to do with Config Server once it has been Final Failover-ed and the VM is up and running in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, failover, server-migration, azure-site-recovery

If a server has been final failover-ed and the VM is up and running in Azure and after that if the configuration server is decommissioned or is unavailable, will there be any impact on the running VM in any possible way ?

Comment: @SadiqhAhmed-MSFT can you help with this ?

Comment: Do you intend failback this VM back to original side? When you failover and commit it, Configuration Server no longer need to be exist. Once you commit, your VM is going to running on your destination in place. In case you want to failback it to the original site, you do need your Configuration Server to reprotect. Also you should consider what is your onprem side (Vmware, Hyper-V and so on), there is a correct approach correct for each technology. Let me know what it is your idea for this VM, I can try to improve this answer here.

Comment: @taguada I don't need to Failback to on-prem. I am basically migrating to Azure. After Migration most of them have been marked- "Complete Migration" (no commit). For few, after Failover,  VMs are up in Azure and neither "Complete Migration" nor Commit as has been done.

Comment: So, in this case, after failover you should complete your migration, please have a look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/migrate-tutorial-on-premises-azure)